# Setting the --user-data-dir for opening PDF files with Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome

In Chrome I have used a custom profile folder at `C:\Pocket\Chrome`. Whenever I open Chrome, I use the path `C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=c:\pocket\chrome` so everything is fine.

However the problem is that whenever I open a PDF file (Chrome is my default PDF viewer), it doesn't use the extension `--user-data-dir=c:\pocket\chrome` so it becomes the "default profile". (Now this is obvious since Chrome open PDF files in "tabs" and If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> it will show the homepage of the "default profile", verifying that it's not using my targeted profile)

I was wondering how do I fix this problem?

==
Windows Vista Home Premium SP 2

Answer (score 0):

**I will keep the instructions below for reference.**

### Windows XP

My Windows is not set to English, so the interface controls can be a bit different.

- Open *Folder Options* (should be in the *Control Panel* or in *My Computer*)
- Select the *File Types* tab
- Select the *PDF* extension and click *Advanced*
- Select the *Open* action and click *Edit...*
- Set the application field to `C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Pocket\Chrome "%1"`

### Windows 7

- Open the Windows Registry Editor (*Win+R* → `RegEdit`)
- Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf`. If the `(Default)` value has any data set, go to the key specified in there.
- Change the data of the `(Default)` value in the `shell\open\command` subkey to `C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Pocket\Chrome "%1"`

Comment: hmm I'm not sure what you mean by the File Types tab. But there isn't such a thing for me: http://screenshoot.me/TmEc4U

Comment: @Pacerier: sorry, I was using Windows XP when I wrote those instructions. I've edited the post to add instructions for Windows 7.

Comment: I'm using Vista I don't have the `shell\open\command` subkey take a look: http://screenshoot.me/KtUiLx

Comment: @Pacerier: Yeah, I thought it could happen... try creating it and delete the ``PersistentHandler`` subkey.

Comment: I've no idea why it's still not working. Am I doing something wrongly?: http://screenshoot.me/xpOQZ7

Comment: Yes. Create the `shell` subkey, then `open` **inside** it, then `command` inside `open`. It should be `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf\shell\open\command` in the status bar.

Comment: Do you mean that the `Data` in `shell` is `(value not set)` ? Am I doing something wrongly again because it's still not working: http://qweop.com/v2 http://qweop.com/v3 http://qweop.com/v4

Comment: Does it work if you delete the `ShellEx` subkey? Also, is Chrome not running or just not loading the correct profile?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1490/discussion-between-kalug-and-pacerier)

Comment: i'm not sure why I can't login to chat.stackexchange.com.. but anyway I've tried the next step but it's still not working. http://screenshoot.me/NPfDLl . It's opening with chrome, but not the correct profile. It's using the default profile

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of *chrome://version/*?

Comment: @ http://screenshoot.me/ymVWXo, btw if you could help me with this chrome issue too that'd be great thx man! http://superuser.com/q/342437/78897

Comment: The profile is right (`Default` is always present). To use another profile, just specify a different folder.

Comment: When I open a pdf file with Chrome, Chrome will not use my custom profile but will use the default profile instead: http://screenshoot.me/EsOtgr