# How to restore Chrome without "Restore" button and the files "Last Session" and "Last Tabs"?

Tags: google-chrome, backup, restore, session-restore

I was using Chrome halfway when the computer crashed. Usually if I restart and re-run Chrome, there would be a <kbd>Restore</kbd> button to recover my lost Chrome session.

However, I restarted **in Safe Mode**, and re-ran Chrome. I saw no <kbd>Restore</kbd> button (just a blank window). Sensing trouble, I restarted the computer in "normal mode" and re-ran Chrome again. But there was still no <kbd>Restore</kbd> button. (Ctrl-Shift-T isn't working either.)

I quickly did a backup of the user data folder, but the files "**Last Session**" and "**Last Tabs**" are only 1 KB each (so the actual data is no longer within those files):

[image]

How do I do a "session restore" now that the <kbd>Restore</kbd> button is gone?

How do I do a "session restore" when Chrome has already overridden "**Last Session**" and "**Last Tabs**"?

(Is there any way to restore the lost session using other files like "History Index" and etc?)

Comment: See also http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19500/tool-to-read-data-from-google-chrome-snss-files/ and http://superuser.com/questions/244325/how-to-restore-the-window-of-tabs-crashed-1-day-ago-in-google-chrome/

Comment: @Vadzim, Also found http://superuser.com/q/635436/78897 . But seeing through all the answers there too, there seems to be **no solution** once Chrome has overridden `Last Session` and `Last Tabs` files. Darn Chrome seriously should provide more data robustness and start  giving more respect to users' data.

Comment: For me right clicking on the browser tab bar, and selecting reopen closed window worked, repeating for each window that was in my previous session,

Answer (score 35):

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --restore-last-session
```

(suggestion was to create a shortcut since this appears to not be a one time occurrence.  I have created the shortcut, but have not tested it yet.)

*Way* back someone posted this solution for basically manually pulling the tabs even after missing the .1 sec 'RESTORE' FROM CRASH.

But I was able to recover my tabs and here is what I did:

- Kill your Chrome via Task Manager
- Go to `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
- Rename "Current Session" to "Current Session.old"
- Rename "Current Tabs" to "Current Tabs.old"
- Rename "Last session" to "Current Session"
- Rename "Last Tabs" to "Current Tabs"
- Restart Chrome and there you go!

This worked after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> would not (no response for even the 1st tab), and after right-clicking on new tab and selecting 'restore' was greyed out. Of course I already had the Settings|'On Startup|Continue where I left off' selected long ago, to no avail.

Now if we could only stop Google from crashing in the first place.

I will be checking out "SessionBuddy extension" for Chrome as well, but this solved last night's dilemma.

**2021 Update:** in recent versions of Chrome paths to Session and Tabs files have changed. They're now all located inside a single folder `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sessions` and have names looking like `Tabs_132655660123456789`. Closing the browser and replacing newer pair of files with the old pair (by renaming them) helps to succesfully recover previous session and even preserve the tab groups - something that SessionBuddy extension can not do.

---

"Default" in "User Data" is a Chrome profile directory. If you have multiple profiles, directories for any additional ones will be named "Profile 1", "Profile 2" and so on.
Of course, if your home/profile directory
is somewhere other than `C:\Users\%username%`, use the appropriate path.

Comment: +1 Awesome (I missed the **1 second** (!?) restore from crash notification - damn you Chrome!) - For those using XP... `C:\Documents and Settings\%username\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

Comment: LastSession and Last Tabs are both 0 bytes. I really doubt this is going to work.

Comment: +1 Awesome, this saved me from a lot of trouble. Thanks! I would give it 2 upvotes, but that is not possible :(

Comment: Great answer! It saved me once more, so I honored it with a bounty. Thanks again!

Comment: Remember, **`--restore-last-session`**.

Comment: Windows crashed on me, so I had to reinstall it, and the old localappdata for Chrome was stored in `Windows.old`, so I copied over the Current/Last Session/Tabs files, and ran Chrome with `--restore-last-session`, and everything was back.

Comment: I backed up the `Last` versions of both files and tried all combinations possible of them and the dubious empty `Current` versions. I start Chrome and crash it manually, replace the files, and start again, get the session restore floating panel, say Restore _aaand_... Nothing happens. Nothing starts.

Comment: Can i suggest that you reverse the order of these suggestions. I had already started chrome once when I notice this problem and started searching for solutions. Then I came here and tried `--restore-last-session`... and now my `Last Tabs` is no longer useful. I'll have to go dig out a backup.

Comment: or at least suggest to make a backup of the `User Data` folder. For reference, on ubuntu linux the folder is in `~/.config/google-chrome`

Comment: Thank you for adding the 2021 Update - it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

The `History Index` files contain your navigation history. The one without dates is from the current month.

With regards to restoring the previous session, try passing `--restore-last-session` in the command line.

Comment: This is working however my "last session" is now not the session I wanted anymore (when it crashed), I'd guess essentially what is required is a `--restore-last-last-session` or a way to copy around the data in `C:\pocket\chrome` such that I can get the `--restore-last-session` to restore the "crashed session".

Comment: Sorry, there is no way to do this, as it only preserves the current and last sessions.

Comment: Where does Chrome save the data for the sessions before the previous session?

Comment: It doesn't. Only the current and previous sessions are stored.

Answer (score 2):

Just gone through that issue now and wanted to restore a browser window, on desktop, with 8 tabs opened.

I solved it by going to browser’s History and there, on top, I could read under “Recently Closed” the following “8 tabs” and “5 tabs”.

From reading the possibilities I just had to press had the “8 tabs”.

I clicked it and the tabs were restored.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the recently closed link

[image: Chrome recent closed]

Your previous tabs are likely to be there.

Comment: I've checked that initially. It wasn't there. Now there is but it is looking like this: http://screenshoot.me/WHzjfA

Answer (score 1):

I have (what I think is) a surefire way of restoring your tabs, as long as you haven't recently deleted your internet history.

Go to history in your browser (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>) and keep scrolling until you start recognizing the links/pages you lost in the crash. Every tab you're looking for should be there in a row. The reason they are, is that Chrome saves your whole sessions every time you start it up.

Comment: This doesn't work for me... I usually kill tabs as they open up... Stuff that has been open for months do not show up in the history...

Comment: this is not helpful if you have a tab that has been open a REALLY long time

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Mac you can use Time Machine:

1. Quit Chrome
2. Navigate to `Users/{your-user}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`
3. Select the file "Last session" and then select "Enter Time Machine"
   from the time machine menu, go back to prior to the crash and
   restore the 4 files:

   - Current Session
   - Current Tabs
   - Last session
   - Last Tabs
4. Launch Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue while my session restore was functioning fine for some time. Suddenly after a forced restart, sessions are not loading and renaming last sessions didn't work.
This worked for me as at 2020 June. I feel my restore setting got disabled due to a chrome setting reset during some previous operation (I did install some new extensions)

- Go to Chrome settings in the current Chrome window ( Assuming you still have the same chrome window where you realized restore is not working)
- Go to start up section
- Select 'Continue where you left off' (If you already have 'continue where you left off' then this method will not work)
- Now terminate chrome from task manager (ensure to disable 'start chrome on start up' setting from task bar hidden icons if you have this enabled before terminate)
- make sure no chrome.exe processes are still running from process tab of task manager
- Now follow the steps below to restore your files. (take a backup of these last session and last tabs files before you start. If they are 1KB size then your previous data is lost)

  - Go to C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
    Data\Default
  - Rename "Current Session" to "Current Session.old"  Rename "Current
  - Tabs" to "Current Tabs.old"  Rename "Last session" to "Current
  - Session"  Rename "Last Tabs" to "Current Tabs" Restart Chrome

Answer (score -1):

Go to History and click Closed Tabs.

It will open another window with all tabs that had been closed previously.