# Lost all Chrome tabs and history after hibernate in Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, hibernate, history, session-restore

I use multiple profiles in Chrome. The main one, for work, had loads of tabs open that I so desperately need.

I recall hibernating Windows 10 a couple days ago.

Just booted Windows and to my disappointment, I did not start off at my last Windows session. Even worse, I opened Chrome and all my tabs were gone and I started on a blank page. No problem, I thought, I'll just recover them from history. bizarrely, my history is blank as well. Odd. I don't recall Chrome updating either. My bookmarks are, however, there. So it appears the profile was not entirely deleted and reset.

I have made a recovery of `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` in case I end up doing something which messes this up more. Are there any other folders I should back up?

Does anyone have any experience with Chrome and know how to recover a last session or corrupted profile (pre-corruption) by messing around with the files?
Firefox saves backup sessions so you can recover your session provided you do not open + close more than once/twice. Does Chrome have the same?

**Updates**

I checked my other profiles on Chrome and all their history are still there. It's just this one profile, which happened to have been my main one, that's missing. I assume this was the only profile open when Windows hibernated.

**Idea**

I didn't mention that the solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/342437/how-to-restore-chrome-without-restore-button-and-the-files-last-session-and?rq=1) does not work because the current session, current tabs, last session, last tabs, etc. files are missing. Completely. Missing. I'll try some recovery software. Though past experience has taught me if a file mysteriously 'vanishes', recovery is futile. **UPDATE:** I performed a deep scan for the 'CURRENT TABS' file. The only file that got detected was deleted only today - hence not the file I need. This shows that if it actually were deleted, it would show up.

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't Chrome saves your history to their server? After you backup, you may want to try signing out from `Chrome` and signing in back again and see if the history synchronized.

Comment: *Are there any other folders I should back up?* - All Chrome user data is store in that location

Comment: This doesn't look like a Chrome problem: You said you hibernated and instead of resuming the system made a clean boot.

Comment: Do you have dual boot with other systems? Other Windows **will** screw up hibernation quite severely, and so will Linux if you choose to force mount.

Comment: 1) I have not signed in with a Google/other account. I should start doing that now. 2) Thanks - it's backed up so I can revert any possible changes. 3) That was what I suspected. However my Chrome profile appears to have been corrupted. My history is missing, but bookmarks 'are' there. Does Chrome not save any backup files, like Firefox? 4) I do not dual boot. I run all other OS' on other drives. Once one OS has been turned off, I sever power to that drive using a 'power switch'. So OS' could not interfere with one another.