# Where does Google Chrome save the startup websites, continue where you left off?

Tags: google-chrome, backup, restore, session-restore

I had to install a fresh Windows 10 on a new SSD.

The SSD on which the previous Windows 10 is installed is OK,
all files can be accessed from `D:\`.

About the favorites, I copied the files located in
`D:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`,
restarted Chrome and all my favorites are back.
But I had a lot of important unbookmarked tabs that used to open on startup.

How do I restore them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore Chrome without "Restore" button and the files "Last Session" and "Last Tabs"?](https://superuser.com/questions/342437/how-to-restore-chrome-without-restore-button-and-the-files-last-session-and)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ramhound, I was looking for how to recover session files
and tabs, so I found :
[How to restore Chrome without "Restore" button and the files "Last Session" and "Last Tabs"?](https://superuser.com/q/342437)

I closed Chrome.
I changed the names of the old files in the previous operating system from the folder :   `D:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sessions`
to names that exist in the Sessions folder of the current system in
the folder :
`%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\`
and then I copied them to the current Sessions folder – I chose to replace the existing files.
I turned on Chrome and all the tabs I had appeared again.

Answer (score 0):

Open `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences` with your favorite text editor.

Comment: I opened it with redirection to `D:\` drive,  ```D:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences``` that opened a long text file with some links at upper part of the text, links that were my shortcuts, but I don't find the unbookmarked tabs. How do I sieve those sites?

Comment: The unbookmarked tabs would be contained within the session file.  If you have copied that file, which would have happened if you copied the entire profile directory, and your session wasn’t restored then you are out of luck. Your only other option would be to point Chrome to open the original profile without moving it.

Comment: @Ramhound, In the folder ```D:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sessions``` I have two files with the word ```Session``` as prefix and two files with the word ```Tabs``` as prefix. How do I use them? Thanks.

Comment: @Asaf - Copy them into your profile directory then launch Chrome.  If your session's tabs do not restore, then you are out of luck, simply as that.